# A doubt on solutions of Schrodinger's Equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I just started reading quantum mechanics, and i am confused regarding a particular fact, which has not been proven in my text directly. My question is:

If $\Psi(x,t)$ is a solution of the time-dependent Schrodinger eqn. , is it also a solution of the time-independent S.E? I could not find any trivial proof for this question, so any help will be appreciated.

Sorry if this is a very basic misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: No, if the $\Psi(x,t)$ is a superposition of two states with different eigenvalues, the it's not a eigenstate of time indep. S.E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions of the time-independent Schrödinger equation $\hat{H}|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle$, where $\hat{H}$ is the *Hamiltonian* of the system, are just the eigenstates of $\hat{H}$. For the time-independent potentials of conservative force fields, $\hat{H}$ doesn't depend explicitly on time, so its eigenstates are also independent of time. The time-dependent Schrödinger equation $i\hbar \partial_t|\Psi\rangle = \hat{H}|\Psi\rangle$, however, dictates the time evolution of the system, and the solution can be written as $|\Psi(t)\rangle = e^{-i\hat{H}t}|\Psi(0)\rangle$ for separable cases. The operator $\hat{U}(t) = e^{-i\hat{H}t}$ is known as the time evolution operator and you can see that since $\hat{H}$ is Hermitian, $\hat{U}$ is a unitary operator, and with the same eigenbasis as that of $\hat{H}$.

So in general, if you start with an arbitrary state $ |\Psi(0)\rangle =\sum c_i|\psi_i\rangle$ *(since energy eigenstates form a complete basis, every arbitrary state can be expanded like this)*, then according to the solution of the Schrödinger equation, after a time $t$, the state is $|\Psi(t)\rangle = \hat{U}(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle = \sum c_ie^{-iE_it}|\psi_i\rangle$, where $ E_i$ is the energy eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenstate $|\psi_i\rangle$. If you are given initially some arbitrary superposition of the energy eigenstates, it remains like that in future and is **not a solution of the time-independent Schrödinger equation**, but a superposition of all its solutions as it was before.

Now imagine you start with $|\Psi(0)\rangle$ being an energy eigenstate instead, say $|\psi_i\rangle$. What happens when you operate it with $\hat{U}(t)$ ? Since $|\psi_i\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\hat{H}$, it should also be an eigenvector of $\hat{U}$, so $|\Psi(t)\rangle =\hat{U}(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle$ becomes just $e^{-iE_it}|\psi_i\rangle$, keeping itself as the eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ and hence **a solution of the time-independent Schrödinger equation**.